# How to get custom events in GA4

Tags: google-analytics

My website is static pages.

Using this gtag.js:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-measurementid"></script>
<script> window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []; function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);} gtag('js', new Date()); gtag('config', 'G-measurementid'); </script>
```

Under Admin I turned off the Enhanced Measurement setting "File Downloads" to allow for my custom event.

Using this event handler:

```
<a href="./special.pdf" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'cw-downloads', 'cw-download-pdf', 'special.pdf',);">Print this page </a>
```

But at analytics.google.com my custom event doesn't show. Both Realtime and in next day's report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
gtag('event', 'login', {
  'method': 'Google'
});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/events

Comment: Thanks. Yes correct. When using gtag event handler it works as expected.

Comment: You're welcome. Mark answer as solved/useful, pls.